# Metasploit with multiple console instances

Tags: metasploit

On `msfconsole`, we can share some things across the same workspace on another instance of `msfconsole` -- for example, `services` and `creds`. However, I see that `sessions` and `route`s are not shared across multiple consoles on the same workspace.

Is this possible? Or is it deliberately removed in the free version of Metasploit?

I know that we can easily background jobs, but it would be nicer to be able to just click a tab to avoid having to do a heavier mental context switch. Sometimes it would also be nice to do multiple things across a pivot without having to background tasks.

Armitage also seems to be able to do a lot of this, but it's quite buggy.

Comment: Cobalt Strike does it by using a client-server architecture where connections are long-lived to the server and ephemerally made available to one or more clients, even simultaneously.  I think it'd be pretty difficult to implement with just client code like Metasploit uses; you'd effectively need to pass sockets around between unrelated processes.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. By the way -- back when the Web GUI was free, could you pass sessions between multiple terminals? I don't remember.